# Samsung Kids Mode - rewrap the presents

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4

I didn't spot an option for this in a quick review, but my 3 year old would like for all the apps and/or all the videos in the Kids Mode application to get re-wrapped so she can open them again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Go to Parental control (Adult+child icon next to open door exit icon)
2. Tap Activity at top and tap Media
3. Remove items you wish to 're-wrap'
4. Go back to the Kids mode (back arrow) and visit the videos app
5. Go back to Parental control and re-add the media.